Determine which tables/columns are encoded by a symmetric key in SQL Server
I have a few keys and certificates in my database, found using
select * from sys.symmetric_keys
select * from sys.certificates

Is it possible to: determine which tables/columns are encoded by each symmetric key
Edit:
I have an encrypted column in tableA. I know it is encrypted by symmetric key sym_key. Is it possible to see what other columns/tables sym_key encodes?
I found
SELECT distinct key_name(column) 
FROM AdventureWorks2022_copy.HumanResources.Employee

Can tell me what symmetric key was used to encrypt my column from the table Employee.
Instead of searching every table/column to determine this info, is there a way to search the other way, by specifying a symmetric key, and seeing all tables/columns that it encodes

i'm not sure, depends on what kind of encryption you use? If you use ENCRYPTBYKEY or friends, it's not really stored anywhere, because it's up to you to use whatever encryption you want per column or row

updated question

How does the code that encrypts stuff look?

You can narrow your search by simply looking for the 3 data types that might support encryption: binary, varbinary, and image. See this query by K. Brian Kelley on MSSQL Tips:

SELECT S.name AS 'Schema', T.name AS 'Table', 
       C.name AS 'Column', ty.name AS 'DataType'
FROM sys.columns C
  JOIN sys.types ty
    ON C.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
  JOIN sys.tables T
    ON C.object_id = T.object_id
  JOIN sys.schemas S
    ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id
WHERE ty.name IN ('binary', 'varbinary', 'image')
ORDER BY S.name, T.name, C.name, ty.name;


